# Laravel 8 checkbox validation that count checked item more than certain value from another field

Tags: laravel, validation, checkbox

i have this blade view

```
<input type="text" value="{{$borongan->worker}}" id="worker" name="worker">
@foreach ($employees as $employee)
<input id="boronganWorker[]" type="checkbox" name="boronganWorker[]" value="{{$employee->empid}}"> {{$employee->nama}}<br/>
@endforeach
```

i need to validate using Laravel validation, that the count of checked item in `boronganWorker` is `gte` than the worker value.

already tried these two,

```
$request->validate(
[
'boronganWorker' => 'required|gte:worker'
]);
\\or
$request->validate(
[
'boronganWorker' => 'required|min:worker'
]);
```

but still cant get the right result.

For example if worker variable have `value=5` :

- if checked less than 5 --> error message.
- if checked `gte` 5 --> pass.

Please help me to find answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is how i solved this problem.

Need to keep the limit on variable, and then use it in the validation using double quotes

```
$limit=$request->worker;
$request->validate([
'boronganWorker' => ['required','array',"min:$limit"]
]);
```

i get the answer from laracast, i dunno if it allowed to share it here, but here it from [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/add-array-size-check-to-validation)

Answer (score 1):

Please use `*` with names. Because when you want to validate array you have to use `*`.

ex.

```
$request->validate(
[
'boronganWorker.*' => 'required'
]);
```